# Tricky rounding conditional rounding conversions to dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to round each value under columns: Q1 24 - Q4 24 to the nearest even # with the exception if: the value is between 0.75 - 3 round to 2 , while creating a new column that captures
its sum.

**Data**

```
state   range   type    Q1 24   Q2 24   Q3 24   Q4 24   rounded_sum     
NY      up      AA      2.39    3.24    3.57    7.07    16      
NY      up      DD      3.53    4.79    5.28    10.45   24      
NY      up      DD      0.51    1.02    2.05    2.05    6       
NY      up      SS      0.59    0.8     0.88    1.75    4       
CA      low     SS      0       0.79    0       0       2       
CA      low     SS      0       0       0       0       0   

import pandas as pd

data = {
    'state': ['NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'CA', 'CA'],
    'range': ['up', 'up', 'up', 'up', 'low', 'low'],
    'type': ['AA', 'DD', 'DD', 'SS', 'SS', 'SS'],
    'Q1 24': [2.39, 3.53, 0.51, 0.59, 0, 0],
    'Q2 24': [3.24, 4.79, 1.02, 0.8, 0.79, 0],
    'Q3 24': [3.57, 5.28, 2.05, 0.88, 0, 0],
    'Q4 24': [7.07, 10.45, 2.05, 1.75, 0, 0],
    'rounded_sum': [16, 24, 6, 4, 2, 0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

**Desired**

```
state   range   type    Q1 24   Q2 24   Q3 24   Q4 24   rounded_sum rounded_sum2
NY      up      AA      2       4       4       8       16          18  
NY      up      DD      4       4       6       10      24          24  
NY      up      DD      0       2       2       2       6           6   
NY      up      SS      0       2       2       2       4           6   
CA      low     SS      0       2       0       0       2           2   
CA      low     SS      0       0       0       0       0           0
```

**Doing**

```
def round_to_even(x):
    if x <= 0.69:
        return 0
    else:
        return int(np.ceil(x / 2) * 2)

# Apply the rounding function to the relevant columns (Q1 24, Q2 24, Q3 24, Q4 24)
df2.iloc[:, 3:7] = df2.iloc[:, 3:7].applymap(round_to_even)

# Recalculate the rounded_sum
df2['rounded_sum_2'] = df2.iloc[:, 3:7].sum(axis=1)
```

However, this is not properly rounding each value under the Q1-Q4 24 headers to the nearest even value (including the exception)

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: *rounding to nearest even number*: `int(np.ceil(x / 2) * 2)` is not the operation you describe, it should be `(x/2).round() * 2`. For example `np.ceil(4.1/2)*2` gives you `6`.

Comment: ok let me try this suggestion....thanks @QuangHoang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `apply`-ing the rounding to each column:

```
subset = df[["Q1 24", "Q2 24", "Q3 24", "Q4 24"]]
rounded = subset.apply(lambda x: np.where(x.between(0.75,3),2,round(x.div(2))*2))
df[["Q1 24", "Q2 24", "Q3 24", "Q4 24"]] = rounded
df["rounded_sum2"] = rounded.sum(axis=1)

>>> df
  state range type  Q1 24  Q2 24  Q3 24  Q4 24  rounded_sum  rounded_sum2
0    NY    up   AA    2.0    4.0    4.0    8.0           16          18.0
1    NY    up   DD    4.0    4.0    6.0   10.0           24          24.0
2    NY    up   DD    0.0    2.0    2.0    2.0            6           6.0
3    NY    up   SS    0.0    2.0    2.0    2.0            4           6.0
4    CA   low   SS    0.0    2.0    0.0    0.0            2           2.0
5    CA   low   SS    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0            0           0.0
```